# Error: 500 Can't connect to example.com:443 (certificate verify failed)

Tags: perl

I get that error. Here is my code.

```
   use LWP::UserAgent;
    use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
    use HTTP::Cookies;

$URL="https://example.com/my.plicy";
$UA = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$UA->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 ); 
#UA->ssl_opts( SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file() );

$req =HTTP::Request::Common::POST("$URL",
   Content_type=>'form-data',
   Content =>[
         'username'=>'111',
         'password'=>'2222',
         'vhost'=>'standard'
   ]
);
$req->header('Cookie' =>q(TIN=287000; LastMRH_Session=439960f5; MRHSession=78c9c47291c1fcedae166121439960f5));


$resp=$UA->request($req);

if( ($resp->code() >= 200) && ($resp->code() <400) ) {
  print $resp->decoded_content;

}else{
  print "Error: ". $resp->status_line. "\n";
}
```

The problem is that I have no real certificate to provide, because the site is in development stages, and a certificate of the localhost is used... the browsers don't recognize it.

Is there a way to bypass the verification?? and avoid the error?

**UPDATE:**

I changed my code a bit. Added another library and added this function:

```
use CACertOrg::CA;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;

$UA->ssl_opts(
    verify_hostnames => 0,
    SSL_ca_file      => CACertOrg::CA::SSL_ca_file()
);
```

Now I get this:

> ---

Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client
is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER
together with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.
If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the
connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set
SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.

---

at C:/Perl/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 31.

So I changed the options to this:

```
    $UA->ssl_opts(
     SSL_verify_mode   => 'SSL_VERIFY_NONE',
    verify_hostnames => 0,
    SSL_ca_file      => CACertOrg::CA::SSL_ca_file()
);
```

I get nothing printed... I don't get an error, though. Is it a good sign?

Comment: Well it's almost 4 years too late, but with regard to the updated part of your question, don't put SSL_VERIFY_NONE in quotes. It's a constant, not a string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add this line after `use ..` part:

```
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
```

Comment: Okay, I have a response printed back. Thanks for the help

Comment: Strangely I had my script working on one client. I moved it to a different client and was getting the same error (500 Can't connect). It was pointing to the same server so I'm not sure what the issue was. This solved my problem.

Comment: Just worked out what the difference is. It's CentOS 7 vs CentOS 6. They must have made things stricter by default with 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
my $UA   = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0, } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Digging up corpses here but I was in the same position and here is what you need to include in order to fix it ;)

```
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_CA_FILE} = "/path/to/your/cert.pem";
```

Only setting verify_hostnames to 0 is not enough when you play around with self signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions worked for me (two and a half years after the last update.. but still it is the top search result so I thought I would add the solution that worked for me) - I needed an additional package to the installation on my Server. It is the  LWP::Protocol::https package that I installed via cpan. To install it I typed into the commandline on my server shell:

```
cpan install LWP::Protocol::https
```

After the package is installed the code works as it was before without any alterations to the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).