# Perl LWP::UserAgent SSL/TLS Inconsistent Certificate Error Message Issue

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp-useragent

I seem to have an odd difference in LWP::UserAgent on Ubuntu and CentOS.

On Ubuntu (14.04.1 with LWP::UserAgent 6.05), if I try to connect to a domain with a self-signed certificate, I get this error message with a 500 error code:

"Can't connect to my.test-domain.com:443 (certificate verify failed)"

That's good. I can see exactly what's wrong - a certificate issue. But on CentOS 7 (also with LWP::UserAgent 6.05) I just get this:

"Can't connect to my.test-domain.com:443".

That's less informative, and as such gives me a problem! Does anyone know how I can kick LWP on CentOS to get the "certificate verify failed" message? Here is the script I test with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $url='https://my.test-domain.com/';
my $browser= LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $tryHEAD=$browser->head($url);
my $responseCode=$tryHEAD->code();
if($tryHEAD->code()==200  ) {    print "OK\n"; }
else {    print $tryHEAD->code().' '.$tryHEAD->message()."\n"; }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397346/error-500-cant-connect-to-example-com443-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: That's probably due to different versions of IO::Socket::SSL used. Please check with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 'warn IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION'`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Thanks, I thought that was going to be it! Ubuntu had IO::Socket::SSL 1.965, CentOS had 1.94. But no. I upgraded both, and I still have the same issue (both are now 2.09)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems related to the version of IO::Socket::IP (which is automatically used by IO::Socket::SSL). Without IO::Socket::IP or with version 0.31 (and probably later) it works as intended while with version 0.25 (Ubuntu 14.04) it does not. This is probably related to changes in the handling of `connect` in version 0.30,0.31.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @SteffenUllrich. On CentOS 7 I had IO::Socket::IP 0.21. Upgrading to 0.36 did the trick.