# Error: 500 Can't connect to foo.com:443 ( unknown errorerror:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3)

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am using `LWP::UserAgent version 6.03` to fetch the status of website.

```
   my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => {verify_hostname => 0},);
   $ua->cookie_jar({});
   $ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
   push @{$ua->requests_redirectable}, 'POST';
   push @{$ua->requests_redirectable}, 'GET';

   my $url = 'https://foo.com'
   $page = $ua->get($url);
   print "Error ".$page->status_line."\n";
```

When I am running this code on my unix machine it giving the following status and the error message for LWP module.

```
   #status
   500 Can't connect to foo.com:443

   #error
   LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown 
   errorerror:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert 
   unexpected message at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
```

I tried to make use of answer [given to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397346/error-500-cant-connect-to-example-com443-certificate-verify-failed) but it did not worked out. Need your valuable advice.

ran the debug

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:193: set domain to 2
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1545: new ctx 74489552
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:334: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:336: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:349: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:379: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:392: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:402: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:412: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a  read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:432: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:392: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1276: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown errorerror:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:398: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown errorerror:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1276: IO::Socket::INET6 configuration failederror:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1582: free ctx 74489552 open=74489552

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1590: OK free ctx 74489552`
```

Comment: Please provide the URL and the version of the dependent modules (probably IO::Socket::SSL) you are using and preferable the version of openssl too. And do you require a proxy?

Comment: IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION : 
`Version1.54`

Comment: Please enable debugging by running your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 app.pl`. For better help provide the OpenSSL version too (`perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 'printf "%x\n", Net::SSLeay::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER()'`. And unless it fails with all URLs you better provide the target host too if you expect help. For now a guess is that it is related to SNI which is only available since 1.56.

Comment: Its failing with this specific url alone.Got to know the host that they have `disable sslv3 on purpose.`

Comment: `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 'printf "%x\n", Net::SSLeay::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER()'` : `90701f`

Comment: Congratulations that you manage to run a 12 year old version of openssl (0.9.7a). Any more help only if the URL is provided.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : the url is of client portal that I cnt share :(

Comment: Then you are unfortunately on your own. There might be a lot of reasons why this fails and you can try to debug it yourself with the help of http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html. If possible I would suggest to you to use recent versions of openssl and IO::Socket::SSL, since lots of todays essential features like SNI, SHA-256 signatures or TLS1.1+ are not supported be the  old libraries you use.

Comment: @made_in_india, We don't need the whole url, just the domain.

Comment: try adding `SSL_version => 'SSLv3'` to your ssl options

Comment: Just a quick note: SSLv3 is considered insecure and many web sites have disabled it (and you'll need to use TLS).  I agree with @SteffenUllrich: you may need to upgrade your libraries.

Comment: the issue was resolved. I just added the `SSL_version => 'TLSv1'` in ssl option

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... This sort of thing happens when some services account for the Poodle vulnerability. I haven't done the research to find the exact cause. It just appears the in some cases the client and server don't properly negotiate the protocol. We've gotten around it by adding `'SSL_version' => 'tlsv1'` to the "`ssl_opts`". I don't really like it though since next protocol upgrade it will need fixing again. I'd far rather let the libraries do the negotiation on their own.